# Execute or skip ld.so.preload shared library code based upon conditions

Tags: c, shared-libraries, ld

TL;DR: Can I just skip loading a shared library placed in ld.so.preload or specific code from it when executing a binary and RUID != UID?

Hi.

I'm writing a shared object, a library, that I load via ld.so.preload in order to hook some functions. I want to know if I can, based upon some conditions, skip loading such library or some parts of it.

Context: I'm working with [TOCTTOU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use) (Time To Check To Time To Use) vulnerability and I'm writing a [userland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space) library, that will be loaded via [linux's loader ld.so.preload feature](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html). The main idea is to hook all functions that operate with files, do some checkings and then call the original function so it's transparent to users and other programs.

Now, the thing is: As I don't want to overload the system and I want my library to have as little impact, overhead as possible, I'd like to execute it, that is, to hook the functions, only when RUID != EUID. That's one of the file-based TOCTTOU premises, it happens when the attacker has lesser privileges than the vulnerable application.

The only way that comes to my mind as of right now is to surround every function declaration with:

```
if(RUID == EUID){
   call original function;
} else {
   do my checkings;
   call original function;
}
```

EDIT: The above code could be replaced by its equivalent, shorter:

```
if(RUID != EUID){
   do my checkings;
}
call original function;
```

But that's actually pretty awful since I'm hooking almost 50 functions plus working with `__attribute` constructor and destructor and It'd mean to fill my code with if-else blocks in each and every single function.

Please bear in mind that ld.so.preload loads the listed libraries before any other library.

I'd like to know if there is any way of just not loading the library based upon the `RUID != EUID` condition or, alternatively, load the library but skip the hooking code.

Comment: I don't really think you can do that autmoagically without having to write some code like the one you showed. You could however build a very small wrapper program which checks if RUID == EUID: if they are equal it does an `exec(target...)`, otherwise first preloads your library then does `exec(target...)`.

Comment: Since my library is system-wide, I cannot create any wrapper for it. @MarcoBonelli That is, I compile it with -shared -ldl flags and simply write its absolute path in /etc/ld.so.preload file.

Comment: then I don't think you can do much, except recompile the loader yourself adding the check you want before looking into ld.so.preload

Comment: I guess you are right, there's not much I can do. I think recompiling the loader itself is a bit to drastic though. I cannot assume that every library placed in ld.so.preload requires the RUID != EUID check.

Comment: Well, you can check the path and name of the lib of course.

Answer (score 0):

> Since my library is system-wide, I cannot create any wrapper for it.

You want to preload your library *only* into setuid or setgid programs.

Since the number of such programs on any system is quite small and statically known (you can find them all with a `cron` job every hour), the easiest solution is to create a wrapper for every such program.

The wrapper can itself be a single very small program that has the exact same setuid / setgid permissions as the "target" program, and performs an equivalent of

```
/bin/env "LD_PRELOAD=..." target-prog args
```

Comment: You are right but please bear in mind I'm addressing TOCTTOU vulnerability. One of its premises is that "the attacker has lesser privileges than the vulnerable program". This is, the attacker takes advantage (exploits) of setuid to root vulnerable programs because the vulnerability allows an attacker to escalate privileges. I know LD_PRELOAD does that but I NEED to execute my library exactly when RUID != EUID, that's why LD_PRELOAD is useless in my context.

Comment: @Razvi I originally inverted your desired behavior. Answer updated.